# How to implement TCP dialing using gvisor's gonet package?

Tags: go, tcp, gvisor

right now i have this implementation of TCP dialing

```
(&net.Dialer{Timeout: conn.TimeOut}).DialContext(s.ctx, "tcp", host)
```

which uses `net` golang library

---

i need to know how to create a custom `network stack` using the capabilities of `gvisor`
and then use it to make TCP connections with `gonet.DialTCP` function from [gonet](https://pkg.go.dev/gvisor.dev/gvisor/pkg/tcpip/adapters/gonet)

---

i tried running this sample script [tun_tcp_connect](https://github.com/google/gvisor/blob/e9bdc76c02bd6ad4c6af574fa1dd31578bec012e/pkg/tcpip/sample/tun_tcp_connect/main.go) that is in gvisor's github repository. i tried to connect to google DNS server with created network stack and expected to receive packets back but there were only outgoing packets that were printed to stdout

Comment: Can you share your current code?

Comment: @Ian there is not much i can share, i tried creating stack like in tun_tcp_connect script i've provided, but since i wasn't able to get even that script itself working, it also didn't work, i'm just not that familiar with networking stuff

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.